# why doesn't (if) work with no mistakes in code

Tags: actionscript-3, animate.css

my code is with AS3 ,( if-else) when i run it doesn't give me a mistake,but also doesn't give me the result of (if) that i want.
the ( tom) object has to be unvisible if touched another object called (food )else (tom) go back to ot's place
the idea is with ( drag and drop )

```js
var hits = 0;
tom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
tom.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);

function mouseDownHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
   var object = evt.target;
   // we should limit dragging to the area inside the canvas
   object.startDrag();
}

function mouseUpHandler(evt:MouseEvent):void {
   var obj = evt.target;
   var target = obj.dropTarget;

   if (target == food && obj == tom) {
      obj.visible=false;
   } else {
      obj.x=1051.05;
      obj.y=135.05;
      obj.stopDrag();
   }
}
```

Comment: In cases like that you **trace** what **obj.dropTarget** is. if conditon is **false** then drop target is not food.

Comment: didn't understand

Comment: Most coding languages has a logging system for telling you what the program is "seeing" or "understanding". In AS3 this **log** is called **trace**, and you log by writing `trace( xyz );` where the `xyz` is replaced by what you need to check, for example using `trace( "The width is... " + obj.width);` tells of your **obj**'s width. When you `trace("your mouse OBJ is.. " + obj);` if the answer given in Output tab is NOT `your mouse OBJ is.. tom` then your `IF/Else` code will not respond.

Answer (score 0):

*"When I run it doesn't give me a mistake, but also doesn't give me the result of `if` that I want."*

That's because there is no error. You don't get a result because your IF condition is never reached. Think about example:  `if (obj == tom)` Here what would ever make `var obj` be **equal to** `var tom`?

**Solution:**

I suspect `food` and `tom` are names, right? Try code to check by instance name...

```
function mouseUpHandler (evt:MouseEvent) :void 
{
    var obj = evt.target;
    var target = obj.dropTarget;

    if (target.name == "food" && obj.name == "tom") 
    {
      obj.visible = false;
    } 
    else 
    {
      obj.x = 1051.05;
      obj.y = 135.05;
      obj.stopDrag();
    }
}
```